# Improving efficiency with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have been using the Entity Framework with the POCO First approach. I have pretty much followed the pattern described by Steve Sanderson in his book 'Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework', using a DI container and DbContext class to connect to SQL Server.

The underlying tables in SQL server contain very large datasets used by different applications. Because of this I have had to create views for the entities I need in my application:

```
class RemoteServerContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    ...

    protected override void  OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("vw_Customers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().ToTable("vw_Orders");
        ...
    }
}
```

and this seems to work fine for most of my needs.

The problem I have is that some of these views have a great deal of data in them so that when I call something like:

```
var customers = _repository.Customers().Where(c => c.Location == location).Where(...);
```

it appears to be bringing back the entire data set, which can take some time before the LINQ query reduces the set to those which I need. This seems very inefficient when the criteria is only applicable to a few records and I am getting the entire data set back from SQL server.

I have tried to work around this by using stored procedures, such as

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> CustomersThatMatchACriteria(string criteria1, string criteria2, ...) //or an object passed in!
{
    return Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("Exec pp_GetCustomersForCriteria @crit1 = {0}, @crit2 = {1}...", criteria1, criteria2,...);
}
```

whilst this is much quicker, the problem here is that it doesn't return a DbSet and so I lose all of the connectivity between my objects, e.g. I can't reference any associated objects such as orders or contacts even if I include their IDs because the return type is a collection of 'Customers' rather than a DbSet of them.

Does anyone have a better way of getting SQL server to do the querying so that I am not passing loads of unused data around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> var customers = _repository.Customers().Where(c => c.Location == location).Where(...
> ```

If `Customers()` returns `IQueryable`, this statement alone won't actually be 'bringing back' anything at all - calling `Where` on an `IQueryable` gives you another `IQueryable`, and it's not until you do something that causes query execution (such as `ToList`, or `FirstOrDefault`) that anything will actually be executed and results returned.

If however this `Customers` method returns a collection of instantiated objects, then yes, since you are asking for all the objects you're getting them all.

I've never used either code-first or indeed even then repository pattern, so I don't know what to advise, other than staying in the realm of `IQueryable` for as long as possible, and only executing the query once you've applied all relevant filters.

Comment: +1. For more 'extensible approach' you can write a function that takes a predicate, and returns either `_repository.Customers().Where(predicate)` or (if it's not IQueryable anymore) write a separate function with `context.CreateQuery<Customer>("Customers").Where(predicate)`, with possibility to call `.ToList()` at the end. It should construct a nice, optimized expression.

Comment: Hi. You were spot on with your suggestion to stay in the realm of IQueryable. I was using an IEnumerable which doesn't pass the query to the server but gets all of the records and then filters them. See the article here: http://www.fascinatedwithsoftware.com/blog/post/2011/06/27/IEnumerable-IQueryable-and-the-Entity-Framework-40.aspx I have checked with SQL Profiler and he's right, IQueryable passes the parameters in as a query

Answer (score 2):

What I would have done to return just a set of data would have been the following:

```
var customers = (from x in Repository.Customers where <boolean statement> &&/|| <boolean statement select new {variableName = x.Name , ...).Take(<integer amount for amount of records you need>);
```

so for instance:

```
var customers = (from x in _repository.Customers where x.ID == id select new {variableName = x.Name} ).take(1000);
```

then Iterate through the results to get the data: (remember, the linq statement returns an IQueryable)...

```
foreach (var data in customers)
{
   string doSomething = data.variableName; //to get data from your query.
}
```

hope this helps, not exactly the same methods, but I find this handy in my code

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's because your Cusomters() method in your repository is doing a GetAll() kind of thing and fetching the entire list first. This prohibits LINQ and your SQL Server from creating smart queries.

I don't know if there's a good workaround for your repository, but if you would do something like:

```
using(var db = new RemoteServerContext())
{
  var custs = db.Customers.Where(...);
}
```

I think that will be a lot quicker. If your project is small enough, you can do without a repository. Sure, you'll lose an abstraction layer, but with small projects this may not be a big problem.

On the other hand, you could load all Customers in your repository once and use the resulting collection directly (instead of the method-call that fills the list). Beware of adding, removing and modifying Customers though.

Answer (score 0):

You need the LINQ query to return less data like sql paging like `top` function in sql or do manual querying using stored procedures. In either cases, you need to rewrite your querying mechanism. This is one of the reasons why I didn't use EF, because you don't have a lot of control over the code it seems.